# I want to specify an array's axes and their index values and get the sub array back

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

So I know how to do this on a case by case basis, but I would like to write a class and method, or have a code snippet to do this in general.  For instance, typically to extract a sub-array I would do:

```
my_array = np.array(range(81)).reshape((3,3,3,3))
sub_array = my_array[0, 1, :, 0]
```

which would return a vector, or 1D array.  I would like to generically have a list of which axes I have index values for, and then supply them to the array (possibly through a new class method) and get back the sub-array.  e.g. for the above:

```
axis_list = [0, 1, 3]
axis_idx_value = [0, 1, 0]
```

or zipped `axes_idx_values = [(0,0), (1, 1), (3, 0)]` and ideally use these in some broadcasting way or some other incredibly slick numpy syntax that already exists.  I tried looking around but I couldn't find anything built in yet, and I'm at a loss on how to first call up a specific (or many) axis and then assign it a index value.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_array[0, 1, :, 0]
```

can also be written as

```
my_array[(0, 1, slice(None), 0)]
```

or

```
idx = (0, 1, slice(None), 0)
my_array[idx]
```

So you could construct that `idx` from your

```
axis_list = [0, 1, 3]
axis_idx_value = [0, 1, 0]
```

Some of the numpy functions that take an axis parameter construct such an indexing tuple.  Some may start with a list or array of the right size, fill in the values, and then convert it to `tuple` for indexing purposes.

Anyways, constructing such a `idx` tuple is straight forward Python, even if it looks a bit messy.  You can hide the mess in a function.

---

```
In [8]: idx = np.full((4,),slice(None))
In [9]: idx[axis_list] = axis_idx_value
In [10]: tuple(idx)
Out[10]: (0, 1, slice(None, None, None), 0)

In [11]: my_array = np.array(range(81)).reshape((3,3,3,3))
In [12]: my_array[Out[10]]
Out[12]: array([ 9, 12, 15])
```

Comment: This was precisely the type of thing I was looking for.  I kept saying to myself "i just want a legitimate place holder, but I can't use ':'... like a slice object..."  Low and behold.  Thanks!